# What is the need of hooks in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, functional-programming

I am an angular developer and started learning React. I got to know that there are two ways a React component can be created.
1. component using React.Component
2. Component without React.Component and using hooks

Since we can achieve everything with React.Component. What is the exact need for React hooks?

Could anyone explain with an example?

Comment: There are two ways you can create component in react. First one is class component and second one is function component. 
Before the introduction of hooks, functional components are just used to dump HTML i.e only for rendering. but after you can do almost everything with functional component.

Comment: LMGTFY https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html